# How to template match the first child node of the root node xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been googling for an hour and none of the answers I've found have solved this problem.

Here is a snippet of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>foobar</groupId>
        <artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0.5</version>
    </parent>

        <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <properties>
        <protostuff.version>1.0.7</protostuff.version>
        <version>2.0.12.0</version>
    </properties>
```

What I would like is to replace the very first 'version' node's value to be changed to something else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>foobar</groupId>
        <artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0.5</version>
    </parent>

        <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>
        <version>THIS HAS CHANGED</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <properties>
        <protostuff.version>1.0.7</protostuff.version>
        <version>2.0.12.0</version>
    </properties>
```

So far this is my xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'THIS HAS CHANGED'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//version[2]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've been playing with the value in "match" and nothing has worked. I've tried "version", "/version", "version[2]". Nothing has worked. I don't know if this matters, but I'm using xsltproc on a red hat server to run the transformation. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="/project/version[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="pReplacement"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```